# Cloud Foundry map-route is not working when path mentioned

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud-foundry

In Cloud Foundry I have pushed two copies of the same application, Say app1 and app2.
I need to route a specific request from app1 to app2. 
Note: app1 and app2 are one and the same, but just i have deployed twice in different name. so the /collections endpoint though it exists in app1, I would like to handle this only via app2 application.So I have created the following routes.

```
cf map-route app2 mydomain.com --hostname app1 --path collections
cf map-route app1 mydomain.com --hostname app1
```

By the above route, I expect https://app1.mydomain.com/collections request to handled by  app2 application.
Except the /collections endpoint, all the other requests (https://app1.mydomain.com/*) are expected to be handled by app1.

Post the above mentioned router mapping also, I could see that https://app1.mydomain.com/collections request is being served by app1.

But when i have only the below route, expecting all the request to https://app1.mydomain.com/* is to be served by app2. this case is working fine.
cf map-route app2 mydomain.com --hostname app1

So I'm having trouble only routing my https://app1.mydomain.com/collections to a app2 application.

Kindly help me in resolving this.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour for overlapping routes is not specified in the documentation, so I think the problem that you're having is that your two rules overlap and there is no way to set a precedence that the most specific rule should win.

The solution would be to have mutually exclusive routes.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. The routes are working only when they are mutually exclusive.