# Cloud Foundry - Context path routing shows 404 Not Found page

Tags: nginx, cloud-foundry, contextpath

I want to use context path routing to access the app that I am trying to deploy. I want the users to  access the app only by using the below URL.

```
https://my-app.domain.int/foo
```

Below is the Staticfile.txt file content.

```
pushstate: enabled
```

Below is the mainfest.yml file content

```
---
applications:
 - name: my-app
   memory: 1G
   instances: 1
   path: .
   routes:
    - route: my-app.domain.int/foo
   buildpack: staticfile_buildpack
```

Below is the directory structure.

```
dist
- index.html
- Staticfile.txt
- mainfest.yml
```

I have tried the following solutions but it didn't help.

1. [Cloud Foundry map-route is not working when path mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803666/cloud-foundry-map-route-is-not-working-when-path-mentioned)
2. [Context routing for two different apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42629961/context-routing-for-two-different-apps)

When I access the URL, I get 404 Not Found page. I want to know if I am missing anything. How can I get the context path to work.

[Note: I am using Azure Pivotal PCF service and nginx server]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename `Staticfile.txt` to `Staticfile` (without extension).

---

The `static_buildpack` (in current implementation) generates `nginx.conf` based on `Staticfile` configuration: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/staticfile/index.html#staticfile

For better understanding try the example below.

### Push the my-app

- `my-app` directory tree:

```
- index.html # with title "root-index" 
- manifest.yml 
- Staticfile 
- public/ 
  - bar/
    - index.html # with title "bar-index"
```

- `manifest.yml`:

```
---
applications:
 - name: my-app
   routes:
   - route: my-app.example.com/foo
   - route: my-app.example.com/bar
   buildpacks: 
   - https://github.com/cloudfoundry/staticfile-buildpack.git # latest
```

- `Staticfile`:

```
root: public
pushstate: enabled
```

### Test it

#### - Check the generated `nginx.conf`:

(`cf ssh my-app` `cat /home/vcap/app/nginx/conf/nginx.conf`)

```
# [...] #
http { 
    # [...] #
    server { 
        listen 8080; 
        server_name localhost; 

        # Based on the Staticfile: "root: public"
        root /home/vcap/app/public;

        # Based on the Staticfile: "pushstate: enabled"
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^(.*)$ / break;
        }

        location / { 
            index index.html index.htm Default.htm; 
        } 
        location ~ /\. { 
            deny all; 
            return 404; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

#### - Test the urls:

- http://my-app.example.com/ - 404 or other app
- http://my-app.example.com/foo - `root-index` because `/public/foo/index.html` doesn't exist
- http://my-app.example.com/bar - `bar-index` because `/public/bar/index.html` exists
- http://my-app.example.com/bar/non-existent.html - `root-index` because `/public/bar/non-existent.html` doesn't exist

Comment: Thank you, just renaming the Staticfile.txt to Staticfile helped me